# c# dropbox api v2 upload memorystream fails

Tags: c#, dropbox

When I upload a filestream the result is correct; when I do the same using a memorystream, the file is created on dropbox, but the data from the memorystream is not uploaded, i.e. the file size on dropbox remains zero. The API does not report an error; it returns a filemetadata object where the file size is zero. Is a memorystream not supported?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After storing data in the memorystream it needs to rewind to the origin: memorystream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin). If you do that right before the upload, all is OK.